# android: Contacts provider working in emulator but not on phone

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract, android-syncadapter

I'm building Contacts provider for android with sync adapter. For now, I have ArrayList of contacts that I'm adding. When I run it on the emulator It's working just fine, but when I run it on the phone (Samsung Galaxy S Plus, Sony Ericsson Xperia X8) I can add the account in Settings, but there isn't the option "Sync Contacts". Any guess what could be wrong or should I post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my xml file defining the preference screen.